# Sort an array of arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of arrays with integers inside, for example:

```
var array = [['1 ', 'C140106'], ['2 ', 'C091815'], ['3 ', 'C140106'], ['4 ', 'C060001']];
```

How can I sort it in order to return something like the following?

```
array = [[4,'C060001'], [2,'C091815' ], [1,'C140106' ], [3,'C140106']];
```

```
  let ans = renglones.sort( (a, b) => {
      return a[1] - b[1]
    })
```

this does not work

Comment: You should probably clarify, on what "column" you want to sort. It seems like it should be sorted by the second value, eg. `C060001`, `C091815` etc?

Comment: What is the result of 'C060001' - 'C091815'? Is it helpful? That's effectively what your sort is doing with `return a[1] - b[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you sort `string`, so you need to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var array = [['1 ', 'C140106'], ['2 ', 'C091815'], ['3 ', 'C140106'], ['4 ', 'C060001']];


const result = array.sort(([_, code1], [__, code2]) => {
   return code1.localeCompare(code2)
})

console.log(result)
```